# Too many if statements? Display div on page depends on hash param

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, hash, query-string

I have multiple pages (about 250) and they each have a button at the end of the page that will send the user to the same page consisting of the download link. So, on click of those buttons the user will be brought to this page that has 250 hidden buttons, but the correct button but will only show if the url has a certain hash param.

I figured out the code below. However, because I have 250 pages, that means that turns into 250 if statements and 250 hidden buttons on the page. Is this too many...is there a better way to do this?

```
<!-- Page 1: -->

<a href="download-page/#download1">Download PDF</a>

<!-- Page 2: -->

<a href="download-page/#download2">Download PDF</a>

<!-- Page 3: -->
<a href="download-page/#download3">Download PDF</a>
```

**Download Page (download-page):**

```
<style>

    #hidden_download1 { display none; }
    #hidden_download2 { display none; }
    #hidden_download3 { display none; }

</style>

<script>
    $(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#download1") {
    $("#hidden_download1").fadeIn(700);
    }
    $(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#download2") {
    $("#hidden_download2").fadeIn(700);
    }
    $(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#download3") {
    $("#hidden_download3").fadeIn(700);
    }
});
<script>

<div id="hidden_download1"><a class="download-btn" href="https://drive.google.com/file/1">Download File</a></div>

<div id="hidden_download2"><a class="download-btn" href="https://drive.google.com/file/2">Download File</a></div>

<div id="hidden_download3"><a class="download-btn" href="https://drive.google.com/file/3">Download File</a></div>
```

Any suggestions? Is this too messy or is it ok? Is there a better way to do this? I'm a bit rusty so please take it easy on me!

Thanks so much!

Comment: are the hrefs able to be constructed based on the hash in the url?  e.g. could you have 1 anchor and set the href depending on the hash?

Comment: Thats a great idea, that would clean up the 250 different buttons on the page. But it would still consist of 250 if statements. Is there a way to clean that portion up?

Comment: Note that the only difference between all these if statements is the number in `download1`. And that this exact number appears in the hash. You could say, that number is a variable…! Which could be read from the hash and put into the place where it’s needed…!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the rule for getting the DOM `id` from `location.hash` Then below code will work fine.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       const id = getIdFromHash();
       $(id).fadeIn(700);
    }
});
<script>
```

You can take a decision on how to write your HTML and `getIdFromHash` function now. I would suggest something like -

```
function getIdFromHash() {
   const hash = location.hash;
   const id = hash; // keep id and hash values same
   return id;
}
```

But if you for whatever reason don't want to keep `hash` and `id` same, then for your original question, this will work

```
function getIdFromHash() {
   const hash = location.hash;
   const id = "#hidden_" + hash.substring(1);
   return id;
}
```